# AWS S3 putObject symbols special chracters

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the aws-sdk for Javascript I'm running into a odd issue where special charaters are not being translated after putting the text into an object

Here is my code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
 region: "us-east-1",
 endpoint: "s3.amazonaws.com"
});

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = {
 Bucket: 'test-example',
 Key: 'test.html',
 Body: 'Copyright © 2017',
 ACL:'public-read',
 ContentType: 'text/html'
}
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
 if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
 else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Which renders to an HTML page that displays:
"**Copyright Â© 2017**"

How do I remove the addition character **Â**

Comment: Did you try to add `ContentEncoding: 'utf8'` to the `params` object?

Comment: utf8 isn't a valid content encoding, @madebydavid.  `text/html; charset=utf-8` however, seems like an appropriate value for `ContentType`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That worked perfectly! Thanks so much!! Want to post it as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this...

```
ContentType: 'text/html'
```

...explicitly tell the browser the character encoding of the content:

```
ContentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
```

This sets both the content [type and subtype](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1) that S3 will return in the HTTP `Content-Type` response header, which the browser uses to correctly interpret the object data.